# Equivalent of C++'s std::bind in Java?

Tags: java, c++, functional-programming, bind

Is there a way to bind parameters parameters to function pointers in Java like you can with std::bind in C++?  What would the Java equivalent of something like this be?

```
void PrintStringInt(const char * s, int n)
{
    std::cout << s << ", " << n << std::endl;
}

void PrintStringString(const char * s, const char * s2)
{
    std::cout << s << ", " << s2 << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::function<void(const char *)>> funcs;
    funcs.push_back(std::bind(&PrintStringInt, std::placeholders::_1, 4));
    funcs.push_back(std::bind(&PrintStringString, std::placeholders::_1, "bar"));
    for(auto i = funcs.begin(); i != funcs.end(); ++i){
        (*i)("foo");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as close as I think you can get to a line by line translation, `bind` does not map 1:1 to any Java construct;

```
static void PrintStringInt(String s, int n)
{
    System.out.println(s + ", " + n);
}

static void PrintStringString(String s, String s2)
{
    System.out.println(s + ", " + s2);
}

interface MyCall {
    void fn(String value);
}

public static void main(String[] argv)
{
    Vector<MyCall> funcs = new Vector<MyCall>();
    funcs.add(new MyCall() { 
      @Override public void fn(String value) {PrintStringInt(value, 4); }});
    funcs.add(new MyCall() { 
      @Override public void fn(String value) {PrintStringString(value, "bar"); }});
    for(MyCall i : funcs){
        i.fn("foo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not, but this code is an approach to mimic the C++ templates (poorly):

```
abstract class Printer<T> {
   final T value;
   Printer( T v ) {
      value = v;
   }
   public abstract void print( String s );
}

class PrintStringInt extends Printer< Integer> {
   PrintStringInt( int v ) {
      super( v );
   }
   @Override public void print( String s ) {
      System.out.printf( "%s, %d\n", s, value );
   }
}

class PrintStringString extends Printer< String > {
   PrintStringString( String v ) {
      super( v );
   }
   @Override public void print( String s ) {
      System.out.printf( "%s, %s\n", s, value );
   }
}

public class BindTest {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Printer<?>[] funcs = {
         new PrintStringInt( 4 ),
         new PrintStringString( "bar")
      };
      for( Printer<?> p : funcs ) {
          p.print( "foo" );
      }
   }
}
```

Outputs:

```
foo, 4
foo, bar
```

Answer (score 2):

From Java7 on, one could do the same also with method handles, see the API doc of class `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle` for details.

Answer (score 2):

Use MethodHandle, here is an example

```
public class HW
{
    int sum;

  public HW(int a, int b)
  {
    super();
    this.sum = a+b;
  }


  public void hello1(double c)
  {
    double newnumber = sum+c;
   System.out.println("hello from hello1, new number= " + newnumber);
  }

  public void hello2()
  {        
   System.out.println("hello from hello2, sum=" + sum);
  }
}

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;


public class TestMethodHandle
{

/**
 * @param args
 */
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    HW hw = new HW(10, 15);
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodHandle mh;
    try
    {
        mh = lookup.findVirtual(HW.class, "hello2",
                                             MethodType.methodType(void.class));
        mh.invoke(hw);

        mh = lookup.findVirtual(HW.class, "hello1",
                MethodType.methodType(void.class, double.class));
        mh.invoke(hw, 20);

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Throwable e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an anonymous class with a function of the desired signature, that forwards calls to the original function.

Let's say you have these functions:

```
public class StringPrinter {
    public void printStringInt( String s, int n ) {
       System.out.println( s + ", " + n );
    }

    public void printStringString( String s, String s2 ) {
       System.out.println( s + ", " + s2 );
    }
}
```

Then you can create anonymous classes that effectively bind arguments to these functions.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
     public interface Print1String {
         public void printString( String s );
     }

     List<Print1String> funcs = new ArrayList<Print1String);
     funcs.add( new Print1String() {
        public void printString( String s ) {
            new StringPrinter( ).printStringInt( s, 42 ); 
        }});
     funcs.add( new Print1String() {
        public void printString( String s ) {
            new StringPrinter( ).printStringString( s, "bar" ); 
        }});

     for ( Print1String func : funcs ) {
         func.print1String("foo");
     }
}
```

Comment: Too many 'new' for me, the two methods of StringPrinter may be static

Comment: In this case those were just an example of what you might want to bind *to*. In general, preferring instance methods to static better supports the possibilities of later inheritance and injection.

Comment: Thats not the same as std::bind, std::bind is dynamic at runtime, this one is static at compile time