# Using boost::function and boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following code trying to pass non-static member functions as a replacement idea to old c code where it requires function pointer.  It is not compiling.  Could you help?  Something must be obvious and I am new to this.  Thanks in advance. -- Jinping

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/function_equal.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>


using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

double addTest( boost::function<double (double)> f, double a, double x )
{

    double a1 = f(a);

    double a2= a1+x;

    return a2;
}

double squareIt (double x) {
    return x*x;
}

class X {
public:
    X(double x0, double x1){ x=x0+x1; }

    double plusIt(double t) { return x+t; }
private:

    double x;

};
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    boost::function<double (double)> f;
    f = &squareIt;

    double result = addTest(f, 10, 5);   //OK

    cout << "result = " << result << endl;

    X newx(10, 15);

    //f=boost::bind(&X::plusIt, &newx);   // does not complie
    double res2 = addTest(boost::bind(&X::plusIt, &newx), 10, 5);  // does  not compile

    cout << "result2 = " << res2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

// compile error:

g++  -Wall -g  -O0 -I/meth_mount/utility_sys/boost_1_42_0/ -I/usr/include  -I/meth_mount/utility_sys/gsl-1.15/ -I/home/ayuan/work/ird_lib/core_lib/alib/intrface/build/alib/clib/linux   -DUNIX -DSET_ENVIRONMENT -DOPTION_RESET -c ./../src/BindTest.cpp 
/meth_mount/utility_sys/boost_1_42_0/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In static member function â€˜static R boost::detail::function::function_obj_invoker1::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0) [with FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t, boost::_bi::list1 > >, R = double, T0 = double]â€™:
/meth_mount/utility_sys/boost_1_42_0/boost/function/function_template.hpp:913:   instantiated from â€˜void boost::function1::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t, boost::_bi::list1 > >, R = double, T0 = double]â€™
/meth_mount/utility_sys/boost_1_42_0/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:   instantiated from â€˜boost::function1::function1(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t, boost::_bi::list1 > >, R = double, T0 = double]â€™
/meth_mount/utility_sys/boost_1_42_0/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1064:   instantiated from â€˜boost::function::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t, boost::_bi::list1 > >, R = double, T0 = double]â€™
./../src/BindTest.cpp:46:   instantiated from here
/meth_mount/utility_sys/boost_1_42_0/boost/function/function_template.hpp:132: error: cannot convert â€˜double (*)(double)â€™ to â€˜doubleâ€™ in return
/meth_mount/utility_sys/boost_1_42_0/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp: In member function â€˜R& boost::_mfi::dm::operator()(T*) const [with R = double ()(double), T = X]â€™:
/meth_mount/utility_sys/boost_1_42_0/boost/bind/bind.hpp:243:   instantiated from â€˜R boost::_bi::list1::operator()(boost::_bi::type, F&, A&, long int) [with R = double (&)(double), F = boost::_mfi::dm, A = boost::_bi::list1, A1 = boost::_bi::value]â€™
/meth_mount/utility_sys/boost_1_42_0/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:32:   instantiated from â€˜typename boost::_bi::result_traits::type boost::_bi::bind_t::operator()(A1&) [with A1 = double, R = double (&)(double), F = boost::_mfi::dm, L = boost::_bi::list1 >]â€™
/meth_mount/utility_sys/boost_1_42_0/boost/function/function_template.hpp:132:   instantiated from â€˜static R boost::detail::function::function_obj_invoker1::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0) [with FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t, boost::_bi::list1 > >, R = double, T0 = double]â€™
/meth_mount/utility_sys/boost_1_42_0/boost/function/function_template.hpp:913:   instantiated from â€˜void boost::function1::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t, boost::_bi::list1 > >, R = double, T0 = double]â€™
/meth_mount/utility_sys/boost_1_42_0/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:   instantiated from â€˜boost::function1::function1(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t, boost::_bi::list1 > >, R = double, T0 = double]â€™
/meth_mount/utility_sys/boost_1_42_0/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1064:   instantiated from â€˜boost::function::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t, boost::_bi::list1 > >, R = double, T0 = double]â€™
./../src/BindTest.cpp:46:   instantiated from here
/meth_mount/utility_sys/boost_1_42_0/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:342: error: invalid use of non-static member function
make: *** [../bin/BindTest.o] Error 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing `_1` which is required because `X::plusIt` is an unary function (not counting `this`). The correct code is

```
double res2 = addTest(boost::bind(&X::plusIt, &newx, _1), 10, 5);
```

See also [Using bind with pointers to members](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.purpose.using_bind_with_pointers_to_memb).

Comment: That's it, thanks!  This approach is so neat.  Are there similar stuff in java?

Comment: Have a look in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053127/equivalent-of-cs-stdbind-in-java